# Failed to convert JSON formatted string kept in sharedPreferance to multi dimensional array

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array, sharedpreferences

> I am trying to save multi-dimensional array of characters in shared 
>    Preference as string JSON formatted and retrieve it back again as valid Java multi dimensional array at anytime.
>
> I tried to use https://github.com/google/gson to convert my `char[][]`
>    array into JSON format to be saved in shared Preference. Below is how I am converting.

This is my multi-dimensional array( `[[e, h, y],[c, i, g, m, c, 4],..]` ) of characters is being converted to `[["e", "h", "y"],["c", "i", "g", "m", "c", "4"],..]` and saved safely to shared Pref by using below code:

```
...
 public static boolean saveArray(Context context,char[][] arrayVar){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
       context.getSharedPreferences("com.domain.project.SharedPrefName", 
        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(arrayVar);
        editor.putString("com.domain.project.arrayName", json);
        editor.apply();
}
...
```

**And This is how it is saved in shared pref:**

```
  <map>
  <string name="com.domain.project.arrayName">[["e", "h", "y"],["c", "i", "g", 
  "m", "c", "4"],..]</string>
   </map>
```

But I expect to convert back that JSON string saved in shared Pref to normal multi dimensional array like this: `[[e, h, y],[c, i, g, m, c, 4],..]` so that I can apply some looping as usual.

Below is the code I am using to decode it back no success:

```
...
public static String getArrayBack(Context context){
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2 =context.getSharedPreferences("com.domain.project.SharedPrefName",
Context.MODE _PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences2.getString("com.domain.project.arrayName", null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Character>>() {}.getType()
        Log.e(RESULT, Arrays.deepToString(gson.fromJson(json, type)));
        return gson.fromJson(json, type);

    }
...
```

As you can see, I am trying to log the result in above method

```
Log.e(RESULT, Arrays.deepToString(gson.fromJson(json, type)));
```

**But I get this error:**

```
   deepToString(java.lang.Object[]) in Arrays cannot be applied 
    to(java.lang.Object)
```

> You guys, could you please help me to figure out where am I wrong? and a kind of help would be highly recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use manual JSON parsing like this:

```
static char[][] getArrayBack(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2 = context.getSharedPreferences("com.domain.project.SharedPrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String json = sharedPreferences2.getString("com.domain.project.arrayName", null);

    try {
        return parseNestedArrays(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

static char[][] parseNestedArrays(String input) throws JSONException {
    final JSONArray array = new JSONArray(input);
    final char[][] result = new char[array.length()][];

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        final JSONArray subarray = array.getJSONArray(i);
        final char[] subresult = new char[subarray.length()];
        for (int j = 0; j < subarray.length(); j++) {
            subresult[j] = subarray.getString(j).charAt(0);
        }
        result[i] = subresult;
    }

    return result;
}
```

After getting your JSON string you create JSON array from it, iterate its elements and then, again, iterate every subarray. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your code works well. Even though, I did come up simple way to accomplish this newbie trick using GSON library before you post this answer. I will go ahead and post it as well. may be it will be quicker solution for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing this quick solution because I guess it would be quicker solution one for some developers for future reference who do not want to do manual JSON parsing as suggested by @kosev. I was using GSON libary wrongly somewhere in my code.

**Below code has made my day**

```
 public static Object[] getArrayBack(Context context){
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2 =context.getSharedPreferences("com.domain.project.SharedPrefName",
Context.MODE _PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences2.getString("com.domain.project.arrayName", null);
       Type type = new TypeToken<Object[]>() {}.getType();

        Log.e(RESULT,  Arrays.deepToString((Object[])gson.fromJson(json, type)));
        return (Object[])gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

The trick was to modify `TypeToken` to `<Object[]>` generic type and modify 
`getArrayBack` method to return `Object[]`. It saves my day.